# how to remove an image in javascript by clicking on it with remove method

Tags: javascript

i am trying to remove image by clicking on it after i create 'img' element using createElement but i cant remove the image , whats wrong with the removes function in  my code ?
here is my code :

```
function generateCat(){
  var image = document.createElement('img')
  var div = document.getElementById('flex-cat-gen');
  image.src= ('image.jpg');
  div.appendChild(image);
}

document.getElementsByTagName('img').onclick =  function removes() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('img').remove();
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `HTMLCollection`, not a single element. You'll have to loop over each element and bind an event listener to it. And in the event handler remove every single image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try like this.You have to add an `Eventlistener` for click event.Also see [document.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName),

> Method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag
>   name

```js
function generateCat() {
  var image = document.createElement('img')
  var div = document.getElementById('flex-cat-gen');
  image.src = ('https://cdn.nikkiflower.com/assets/uploads/product_image/114/small/1575008384_0.jpg');
  div.appendChild(image);


  let tags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    tags[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

      this.remove()

    })

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-cat-gen">
</div>

<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="generateCat()">Generat Cat</button>
```

Comment: this is my html : <button class="btn btn-warning"  onclick="generateCat()">Generat 
                           Cat</button>  so i dont have to add eventlistner

Comment: thank u now its working

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked @amir